# MySQL SELECT MONTH regresa NULL

Tags: mysql, trigger

Estoy creando un trigger el cual debe insertar el usuario, mes y año. El problema es que inserta el mes como NULL.

El usuario y el año los inserta correctamente pero parece que no obtiene el mes. Las fechas llegan a la base en este formato `2020-02-17` el campo Fecha es de tipo Date, y si hago la consulta `SELECT MONTH(Fecha) FROM lista_day` me regresa el mes, en este caso 2.

El código de mi trigger es el siguiente:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `control` AFTER INSERT ON `lista_day` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

DECLARE total_final INT(11);

DECLARE year_actual INT(5);

DECLARE mes_actual INT(2);

SET total_final = (SELECT count(*) FROM control_table WHERE Usuario=NEW.Usuario AND Year= (SELECT YEAR(NEW.Fecha)) AND Mes=(SELECT MONTH(NEW.Fecha)));

 SET year_actual =(SELECT YEAR(NEW.Fecha));

 SET mes_actual = (SELECT MONTH(NEW.Fecha)); 


    IF total_final = 1      

            THEN

                                    UPDATE control_table SET
                                                control_table.Count=control_table.Count +1

                                            WHERE  
                                                control_table.Year=year_actual
                                            AND 
                                                control_table.Mes=mes_actual
                                            AND 
                                            control_table.Usuario=NEW.Usuario;
            ELSE

                                        INSERT INTO control_table SET

                                            control_table.Count=1,
                                            control_table.Year=year_actual,
                                            control_table.Mes=mes_actual,
                                            control_table.Usuario=NEW.Usuario;


    END IF;             

END
```

Answer (score 1):

Analizando tu script me doy cuenta que estas usando un valor que no has seteado:

```
NEW.Fecha
```

Debes setearlo tal como lo has hecho con las otras variables ej:

```
SET NEW.Fecha = SELECT MONTH(NOW());
```

Luego de eso, la variable tendría un valor.

Comment: No fue la solución pero gracias, al colocar `SET mes_actual = (SELECT MONTH(NOW()); ` (Esto devuelve el mes actual y no el mes que se inserto en la tabla `lista_day`) me di cuenta de 2 errores , el primero es que igualmente colocaba `NULL`, y era por un error en mi trigger `control_table.Mes=mes_actual ` , al corregir este error seguía insertando NULL, así que pedí el diccionario de datos y me di cuenta que Year si estaba declarado como INT pero Mes estaba declarado como datetime por eso no lo reconocía como una fecha valida e ingresaba NULL

Comment: si, te puse NEW.Fecha = SELECT MONTH(NOW()); a modo de ejemplo para temas de fechas, pero excelente que hallas encontrado el error, felicitaciones.